# How to evaluate inequalities involving integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration

For example if $f(x)$ defined at $[0,\infty)$ as:

$f(x)=\int_x^{x+1}\sqrt{\arctan t}\;dt$

And I need to show to for every $x\ge0$

$f(x)<\sqrt{\arctan(x+1)}\;;$

I dont understand how to show this.

Need some guidelines.

Comment: Maybe use the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus to differentiate both sides?

Comment: $x \in [x, x+1]$ is always true since x = x so according to that, you showed the inequality already for every $x \geq 0$

Comment: @Xoque55 I dont see how should I do this

Comment: @CandyOwl I edited the post. thanks.

Comment: @idan di Allow me to do some copy & paste: $x \in [x, \infty)$ is always true since x = x so according to that, you showed the inequality already for every $x \geq 0$

Answer (score 2):

The property you have to establish is generalizable in this way:

If $\varphi$ is any (a) continuous and (b) strictly increasing and (c) taking positive values, one has

$$\int_x^{x+1}\varphi(t)\;dt < \varphi(x+1)$$

Explanation: take the intermediate value theorem which asserts that there is $\xi \in (x,x+1)$ such that $\int_x^{x+1}\varphi(t)\;dt=((x+1)-x)\varphi(\xi)=\varphi(\xi)<\varphi(x+1)$.

Here, take $\varphi(x)=\sqrt{atan(x)}$.

The only property we have to check is (b) that this function $\varphi$ is strictly increasing.

Indeed, $\varphi'(x)=\dfrac{1}{2 \sqrt{atan(x)}(1+x^2)}>0$

Comment: But the intermediate value theorem talks about closed interval $[x,x+1]$
so $\xi$ can be equal to $x+1$

Comment: @idan di For strictly increasing functions, it is (x,x+1) (a fact that is evident if you draw a figure)

Comment: yes,I see it when looking at the function graph.but how can I proove this formaly? that $\xi$ cant be $x+1$

Answer (score 0):

More generally,
if $a < b$
and $f$ is integrable,
$\min_{x\in (a,b)} f(x)
\le \frac1{b-a}\int_a^b f(x) dx
\le \max_{x\in (a,b)} f(x)
$.

All this says is that
the average value of a function
is between
(and possibly equal to)
its min and max.

This formulation applies
to increasing or decreasing
functions.

If $f$ is increasing,
$\min_{x\in (a,b)} f(x)
=f(a)$
and
$\max_{x\in (a,b)} f(x)
=f(b)$;
the reverse holds if
$f$ is decreasing.

Comment: but why $f(x)=\int_x^{x+1}\sqrt{\arctan t}\;dt$ can't be equal to $\sqrt{\arctan(x+1)}$?

Comment: Because the function is increasing.